# datastore: invalid entity type on get

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Hey  im trying to get  an entity by passing an  id ,

But it`s look like im getting a **nill pointer**
I tried to initialize the entity in couple  of ways but the result is the same.

I'm trying  to create my server  as much as i can like this example 
[to-do](https://github.com/campoy/todo/blob/master/task/task.go)

what am im missing here ?

```
type UserManager struct {
    users []*Users
    user  *Users
}

func NewUserManager() *UserManager {
    return &UserManager{}
}

 func (userManager *UserManager) putUser(c appengine.Context, u *Users) (usreRes *Users, err error) {

key, err := datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "users", nil), u)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
 }
c.Debugf("file key inserted :%#v", key)
return u, nil
}


func (userManager *UserManager) getUserById(userKey string, c appengine.Context) (usreRes *Users, err error) {

entity_id_int, err := strconv.ParseInt(userKey, 10, 64)

if err != nil {
    return userManager.user, err
}
k := datastore.NewKey(c, "users", "", entity_id_int, nil)

userRes := new(Users)
err = datastore.Get(c, k, &userRes)

//err = datastore.Get(c, k, &userManager.user)

if err != nil {
    return userManager.user, err
}

//return userManager.user,nil
return userRes, nil
}
```

Comment: Where is your full code? Where is userKey defined? What do you mean by tried couple of ways? Just hustling pointers and references won't magically fix your problem.

Comment: @Allendar i added the putUser method  ,
this is how  i insert a user

Comment: I still don't really get it tho. Nil-pointer itself mostly means that someone uses a value while a checked error should've told you that the code went wrong at an earlier point. Nil-pointers imply a unfilled peace of memory. If this is a value coming from Google's own API, then the only conclusion is that an error-check isn't done. If it's your own code, then its likely a fault in your type-assignment. It's a common mistake to put wrong memory references in memory-pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `datastore.Get(c, k, "pointer")` expects a pointer to struct as its third argument, and you are passing a pointer of a pointer `**userRes`

```
userRes := new(Users)
```

There you are creating a pointer to struct [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543430/golang-basics-struct-and-new-keyword)

So you should do:

```
datastore.Get(c, k, userRes)
```

Without the ampersand, because with new keyword you are already creating a pointer