# Golang basics struct and new() keyword

Tags: pointers, struct, go

I was learning golang, and as I was going through the chapter that describes Structures, I came across different ways to initialize structures.

```
p1 := passport{}
var p2 passport
p3 := passport{
    Photo: make([]byte, 0, 0),
    Name: "Scott",
    Surname: "Adam",
    DateOfBirth: "Some time",
}

fmt.Printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", p1, p2, p3)
```

While these print the values of the structures as

`{   }
{   }
{ Scott Adam Some time}`
, the following code below prints with an ampersand because it is a reference.

```
pointerp1 := &p3
fmt.Printf("%s", pointerp1)
pointerp2 := new(passport)
pointerp2.Name = "Anotherscott"
fmt.Printf("%s", pointerp2)
```

`&{ Scott Adam Some time}&{ Anotherscott  }`

Kindly help me with my doubts.

1. in the usage `pointerp1 := &p3`, `pointerp1` is the reference variable to `p3`, which holds the actual data. Similarly, what would be the actual variable that holds the data for `pointerp2`?
2. What would be the best scenarios to use these different types of initialization?

Comment: Go has no notion of "references". Don't name pointers "references".

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`new` allocates zeroed storage for a new item or type whatever and then returns a pointer to it. I don't think it really matters on if you use `new` vs short variable declaration `:= type{}` it's mostly just preference

As for `pointer2`, the `pointer2` variable holds its own data, when you do

```
// initializing a zeroed 'passport in memory'
pointerp2 := new(passport)
// setting the field Name to whatever
pointerp2.Name = "Anotherscott"
```

`new` allocates zeroed storage in memory and returns a pointer to it, so in short, new will return a pointer to whatever you're making that is why `pointerp2` returns `&{ Anotherscott }`

You mainly want to use pointers when you're passing a variable around that you need to modify (but be careful of data races use mutexes or channels If you need to read and write to a variable from different functions)

A common method people use instead of `new` is just short dec a pointer type:

`blah := &passport{}`

blah is now a pointer to type passport

You can see in this playground:

http://play.golang.org/p/9OuM2Kqncq

When passing a pointer, you can modify the original value. When passing a non pointer you can't modify it. That is because in go variables are passed as a copy. So in the `iDontTakeAPointer` function it is receiving a copy of the tester struct then modifying the name field and then returning, which does nothing for us as it is modifying the copy and not the original.

Comment: `iDoTakeAPointer` function also receives a copy of the pointer (but the data it points to is exactly the same).

Comment: I find `new` a completely bizarre decision from the go team, `&` is what other languages use, `new` seems like you're allocating memory and copying the item to it which is the inverse.

Comment: @Dominic couldn't agree more, coming from C++, it seems very counter-intuitive

Answer (score 5):

All the new keyword does is basically create a instance of the type you want. However instead of returning the plain declaration of the type, it references it and return the acutal memory address of that type in the program process heap.

Answer (score 4):

1. There is variable that holds the data yet. You can dereference the pointer using `*pointerp2`, and even assign it that to a variable (`p2 := pointerp2`), but this variable would be a copy of the data. That is, modifying one no longer affects the other (http://play.golang.org/p/9yRYbyvG8q).
2. `new` tends to be less popular, especially with regard to structs. A good discussion of its purpose (hint: it came first) and use cases can be found at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/216582.

Edit: Also, `p1` is not really a different kind of initialization from `p3`, but instead of assigning a value to any of the type's fields they are initialized to their zero value (`""` for `string`, `nil` for `[]byte`). The same would happen for any omitted fields:

```
p4 := passport{
    Name: "Scott",
    Surname: "Adam",
}
```

In this case, `p4.Photo` and `p4.DateOfBirth` would still be zero-valued (`nil` and `""` respectively). The `passport{}` case it just one where all the fields are omitted.

Comment: @Datsik It *prints* `[]`, but its value `nil`; see https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11. There's also a good discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/vNodYyoUu9Q. TL;DR: a nil slice acts like an empty slice in many ways. ["This is intended behaviour and even documented behaviour."](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12780#issuecomment-144051177).

Comment: I'm aware of that, but just for the next new commers to read this should understand that, even though they see [] it is still actually nil. Case in point would be getting null for a json value: http://play.golang.org/p/GiQnKssZjH even though when you're debugging you think you have an empty slice

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing strange phenomena in golang where my pointer declared as `myptr:= new(ptrtype)`
was resulting in false from `if myptr==nil`, so I went ahead  and tried defining it as `myptr:=&ptrtype{}` and still didn't work.  So then I just defined the pointer with new() and then i set it = nill and now it works.  don't know why I didn't have to do that with the other ones.